# I want to split the powershell-command txt document

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am a Windows 10 user.

This is the command below.

```
powershell -command "& {get-content log.txt|select-object -first 100}" >out_log111.txt
```

This is what I saw on the website. (Success!)

.

I applied it as below.

```
powershell -command "& {get-content log.txt|select-object -first (100..200)}" >out_log222.txt
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jFGX.png

An error occurs. (Failed)

.

.

I want to split the log.txt document.
I want to print from the first 100 onwards to 200.

And the rest.

I'd like to print out 200 to 300 next time.

in order

200~300 `out_log333.txt`

300~400 `out_log444.txt`

I'm going to file a long log.txt file

I'd like to divide by numbers in `cmd`. (`bat file`)

in hundred lines

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `-Index`, not `-First`, and because the indexing begins at `0`, the command you should be using is:

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile^
 "Get-Content -Path '.\log.txt'"^
 " | Select-Object -Index (99..199) > '.\out_log222.txt'"
```

*I have split the command over three lines for readability, but you could leave it as one if you preferred.*

Comment: `powershell -command "& {Get-Content inlog.txt | Select-Object -Skip 100 -First 100}" >outlog.txt` Thank you for your answer. Here's another person's advice. Thank you all for your help.